# leaflet circle drawing / editing issue

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am working on leaflet for the very first time and facing the issue with drawing circles and editing (changing location of circle).

**The problems I am facing are :-**

1. Editing (moving) circle from one location to another changes its radius.
   **Note:** Pls try to create circle on top of map in given fiddle and then move it to the bottom by clicking edit button.
2. If I create circle on top section of map it works fine. But If I create circle on bottom of map it only prints a single DOT on map. 
   I checked few examples and it works fine everywhere.
   **[Here is the working example](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/)** where circle creation and moving circle is completely fine.

I am not using the geographic map like google maps. I am using and static image as it is my project requirement.

Here is the **[fiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/newBee_/88bdrzkr/)**.

Just using following code to enable drawing circle :

```
enabled : this.options.circle,
handler : new L.Draw.Circle(map,this.options.circle),
title : L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.buttons.circle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is distortion in distance inherent in the mercator projection (and the Google Mercator projection based off it that is inherent to most online maps).  Because your map starts at zoom 1, dragging the circle marker north/south will cause a lot of distortion.

So, rather than georeference your image to a global bounding box, try georeferencing it to something much smaller.  In your case, your are adding your image overlay relative to the maxZoom, so by increasing maxZoom, your image will be overlayed over a smaller area of the globe, and you will see less (or no) distortions across latitudes.

I changed the maxZoom from 4 to 14, and the result looked like it worked well: [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jameslaneconkling/mhpd9ca5/):
        var w = 553, h = 329, url = 'https://kathleenmillar.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/picture2.png';

```
    var map = L.map('map', {
        minZoom : 10,
        maxZoom : 14,
        center : [ w / 2, h / 2 ],
        zoom : 11,
        crs : L.CRS.Simple

    });

    // calculate the edges of the image, in coordinate space
    var southWest = map.unproject([ 0, h ], map.getMaxZoom() - 3);
    var northEast = map.unproject([ w, 0 ], map.getMaxZoom() - 3);
    var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
```

Comment: Can you please suggest that what is the possible solution to resolve this issue? Please check fiddle if possible.

Comment: Updated my answer with link to a revised fiddle.

Comment: By the way, kudos for using leaflet for architectural rendering.

Comment: Thanks alot James. You are champ :D . Issue resolved. Your last comment sounds like leaflet is not a perfect fit for architectural rendering. Can you please suggest any other api for this work that supports all these features :) . Thank again .

Comment: Well, leaflet might very well be a perfect fit (or a good enough fit), even though it was originally designed to display geographic data on a mercator projection (which you get around by reprojecting your non-georeferenced image onto the geographic space).  If you're interested [read more about this kind of web mapping technology](http://www.macwright.org/2012/05/15/how-web-maps-work.html).  If you run into limitations with leaflet, though, maybe checkout [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), which will give you a lot (maybe too much) freedom.  If you run into issues, post back here.

Comment: Thanks alot james for ur kind suggestions.  Though I have achieved most of the required functionality by using leaflet but kind of stucking somewhere with these kinds of issues like you just resolved. Will ask you again in case I stuck again :) .Thanks again.

Comment: Hi james, Can you please suggest any solution for my the below problem? I posted it on github but no response as of now. Here is the link https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/388

Comment: @NewBee yeah, GitHub's issue tracker is generally used to post about bugs in the code base that the maintaining developers would need to fix.  Try posting that same question to stackoverflow as a new question.

Comment: *As for my two cents on the question*, because you are trying to save user input to a database, the core of your question needs to address how you plan to set up that database and do stuff like authenticate users.  The javascript you write to access and save to that db is a comparatively minor problem.  Setting up a db is not a trivial thing to do.  It involves doing quite a bit of server-side set-up and maintenance, or going through a third party API.

Comment: Hi james, Can you suggest something on this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023788/adding-jquery-ruler-on-leaflet-map