# Adding jquery ruler on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I need a ruler on leaflet map along X,Y axis but leaflet API does not support it and there is no plugin available.  There is a jquery ruler that servers my needs.  Is it possible to add jquery ruler on leaflet map ?

Here is the example :
http://ruler.hilliuse.com/

The ruler must adjust to the zoom level of leaflet map also. Please suggest.

Comment: For background, you should probably mention that you are hacking leaflet to display architectural house plans (rendered on a flat xy plane), reprojected onto leaflet's spherical mercator projection.  See [this previous discussion on the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366268/leaflet-circle-drawing-editing-issue/29382236?noredirect=1#comment48164774_29382236).  This is important b/c leaflet assumes your images are being projected from a sphere, not a plane.

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate the corners of the map after every zoom, then just reset the start point of the ruler ;). May be you have to write some logic for getting corners coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't taken a deep look into the code of either, but here's the trade off:

- leaflet's [scale-control](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-scale) will already be hooked up to leaflet zoom events.  Should be possible to duplicate the x-axis and rotate it 90º as a y-axis.  However, keep in mind that leaflet scale-control is meant to measure distance on a spherical surface (i.e. the earth), not a flat xy plane.
- the jquery ruler plugin should be easier to hack, internally, b/c it is not supposed to measure spherical distance.  You'll have to update it's values on zoom, though.  Check out the leaflet [zoomend](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomend) event.  Use it like this:

`map.on('zoomend', function(event){
  updateRuler(...);
});`

[leaflet event docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#event-objects)