# leaflet fixed size circle on map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet.js to create few markers and circles. I am using the below given code to draw circles : -

```
 L.circle([ lat, lng ], 1000, {
            color : colorCode,
            stroke : false,
            fillColor : colorCode,
            fillOpacity : 0.7
        });
```

Now if I edit this circle on UI and drag this circle vertically downwards, the circle size increases and vice a versa. Similar issue is with calling the above given method with different lat lngs.  The same radius (1000) sized circle get plotted with different sizes on map.

My requirement is to place marker with same radius with same size on map everywhere.

I checked L.circleMarker but it takes radius in pixels and also circleMarkers does not scale in zoomin zoomout events. That is why I can't use circleMarkers.

I changed the crs option to 4326 but no success. I am using imageOverlay not tileset. I have created a fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/newBee_/88bdrzkr/12/

Try creating a circle on top area then edit and move it downwards. It's size increases. This is what I want to stop. This will resolve the problem of generating circle of same radius via code in different area of map with same size. Please help.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

It looks like this is a [bug deep into Leaflet 0.x](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/stable/src/layer/vector/Circle.js#L73-L81): L.Circle radius computation uses hard-coded Earth projection rather than the specified CRS. Leaflet 1.0 seems to correctly check for the CRS before using the Earth-related computation.

For your case, simply overriding the faulty method seems to fix it, at least visually.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/88bdrzkr/13/

The "corrected" method to include in your script:

```js
L.Circle.include({
    _getLngRadius: function () {
        return this._getLatRadius();
    }
});
```

Regarding iH8's answer, the trick to override `L.CRS.Simple.scale` is similar to highly zooming (the `256` factor expands the latLng to much further pixels - any high number will do). At high zoom, you are moving your circle along a very short distance, for which the latitude does not change much. So you do not see any visible difference in radius, even though the bug is still there.

Demo of using just higher zoom, no method override at all: http://jsfiddle.net/kau6g8fk/1/

For your need where the circle looks to be more like a visual aid, any of these 3 solutions is enough.

---

Edit: the CRS is not the issue at all.

Previous message:

If you use Leaflet for indoor mapping, as your jsFiddle suggests (or any flat type map, as opposed to the projection of a sphere like Earth on to a plane), you could simply use `L.CRS.Simple`

Comment: The Fiddle uses `L.CRS.Simple` :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I did not pay attention indeed! :-)

Comment: :) After some more research i came up with the same conclusion and wanted to share but i see you beat me to the punch. Good stuff, thanks for sharing. Found the same question by the same user (?!?!) which has a similar solution of upping the min/max/zoom levels which turned me on the right path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366268/leaflet-circle-drawing-editing-issue

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link! Interesting to see someone actually asking twice whereas the first question was acknowledged as having a working solution. For the described use case, I think any of the 3 given workarounds should be good enough.

Comment: Yes. I asked the same question again. That time the issue was resolved by setting high zoom level. I created circles and moved and thats fine ( but behind the scene there was a minor size issue) . Now when I populated circle of same radius on whole map(image). The same radius circle was populated with different sizes . So I stucked again. Previous thread worked for me in one use case and failed in second use case :( .  And yes, thaks alot for the exceptional effort. You guys really saved my life :D

Comment: Now we have two solutions for this issue : increase zoom level or override _getLngRadius . Perfect. Thanks @Ghybs and iH8

Answer (score 1):

Striked out this faulty solution as pointed out by Ghybs in his answer

<strike>Very weird issue, turns out that overloading `L.CRS.Simple`'s `scale` method to return `256 * Math.pow(2, zoom)` fixes this. Here's a fork of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kau6g8fk/ I'm unsure as to the cause of this issue, it would require more research. Will do if i find the time. Found the solution here: http://codepen.io/mike_beweb/pen/BymKGe</strike>

The answer below was given before the poster edited his/her question and showed that the used CRS was L.CRS.Simple while i presumed the default CRS. I'll leave it in tact because it might come in handy for some users:

The size change on drag of your `L.Circle`'s is because of your map's default spherical mercator projection (EPSG:3857). Best explained with an image, here's a map with a graticule overlay on every 10 degrees:

[image]

Demo on Plunker: [Leaflet 0.7.5 EPSG:3857 Spherical](http://embed.plnkr.co/lQhxRj/preview)

As you move further from the equator every plane becomes higher. Thus your circle automaticly becomes higher the further north/south you drag it. You could use a equirectangular projection (EPSG:4326), in which every plane has the same size regardless of the distance from the equator:

[image]

Demo on Plunker: [Leaflet 0.7.5 EPSG:4326 Equirectangular](http://embed.plnkr.co/Ww5TXtfl7YcrxYDfgoWs/preview)

With equirectangle projection you won't have the problem you're having now but you'll have to change your tileset to one with EPSG:4326 projection and those are hard to come by compared to EPSG:3857 tilesets.

If you're not willing or unable to change projection another solution could be to hack around L.CircleMarker and change the radius of your markers depended on current zoomlevel. But that's rather ugly in my opinion.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I switch to equirectangular projection?

Comment: Whoops, truly sorry. I see i linked the wrong example for equirectangular. Corrected now. You can review the code in the example: http://embed.plnkr.co/Ww5TXtfl7YcrxYDfgoWs/preview It's just a matter of setting `L.Map`'s `crs` option to  `L.CRS.EPSG4326` and adding a EPSG4326 tilelayer. I used WMS, first one i could find with google but there are others, just do a search.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help :) . I changed the crs option to 4326 but no success. I am using imageOverlay not tileset. I have created a fiddle.  Try creating a circle on top area then edit and move it downwards. It's size increases.  :(   . This is what I want to stop. This will resolve the problem of generating circle of same radius via code in different area of map with same size. Please help

Comment: Would you be so kind to add that information to your original question by editing it. Unable to give a proper answer in the comments, that's not what they are meant for

Comment: I've udpated the original question and added the info. :)

Comment: Edited my answer, has a solution for now :) Good luck