# Finding shortest path in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have collection of points within line on map using L.pather plugin. Also I have markers populated on map. Given any two markers, I want to find the shortest distance(path) on the map on the previous provided line . Attached is image for reference.

[image]

Here I want to draw a line between A and B on the given path (blue line). Blue dots on line are the collection of point (lat,lng) that I have. Is there any way I can do that ?

Comment: Have you tried accomplishing what you wanted with `distanceTo`(http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto) yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `distanceTo` method of `L.LatLng` to calculate the distance from your `L.Marker`'s latlng to each  latlng of your polyline:

```
function getNearestPointOnPolyline (marker, polyline) {
  var nearestKey,
      nearestDistance,
      markerLatLng = marker.getLatLng(),
      polylineLatLngs = polyline.getLatLngs()

  for (i = 0; i < polylineLatLngs.length; i++) {
    var distance = markerLatLng.distanceTo(polylineLatLngs[i])
    if (!nearestDistance || nearestDistance > distance) {
      nearestKey = i
      nearestDistance = distance
    }
  }
  return nearestKey
}
```

If you calculate that for each marker, you can use the `spliceLatLngs` method of `L.Polyline` to trim the polyline to those points:

```
var polyline = new L.Polyline([...]).addTo(map),
    marker_a = new L.Marker([...]).addTo(map),
    marker_b = new L.Marker([...]).addTo(map)

// Get key of nearest point on polyline
var nearest_a = getNearestPointOnPolyline(marker_a, polyline),
    nearest_b = getNearestPointOnPolyline(marker_b, polyline)

// Determine start and end key
var start = Math.min(nearest_a, nearest_b),
    end = Math.max(nearest_a, nearest_b)

// Splice all keys untill start key
polyline.spliceLatLngs(0, start)
// Splice all keys from the end
polyline.spliceLatLngs(end - start + 1,polyline.getLatLngs().length)
```

Reference:

- http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto
- http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline-splicelatlngs

Comment: Perfect. You rock @iH8. Thanks alot :)  . Can you please help on my previous question too :     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233646/leaflet-fixed-size-circle-on-map

Comment: Given a latlng array. Can I get the shortest path between two nodes in leaflet?

Comment: The function i posted iterates an array with `L.LatLng` objects (coming from a polyline) and measures each distance to another `L.LatLng` object (coming from the marker) If you want to do the same with an array containing arrays with coordinates you need to turn them into `L.LatLng` objects first so you can use the `distanceTo` function of `L.Latlng` Or am i misunderstanding your latest comment? As for the first comment, no thanks :) you're always welcome. I'll look into it as soon as i find the time. I suspect a bug though :(